# NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS does not block an assertion in a static library

Tags: objective-c, nsassert

NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS does not block an assertion failure coming from a static library.  How do we suppress assertion failure coming from a static library?

Comment: How to block the assertion failure in a static library? NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS doesn't suppress that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` must be defined at compile time. If the library has been compiled with assertion code that you want to suppress (which sounds *extremely* dangerous), you will need to create a subclass of [`NSAssertionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAssertionHandler_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that ignores those particular failures and install it in the [thread dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/threadDictionary).